# Error while building using TFS build server

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

This error I am getting when I am running build using TFS, and I don't have any clue as to what to do:

I am using TFS 2013.

> Exception Message: TF201077: The work item type Bug cannot be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed. (type WorkItemTypeDeniedOrNotExistException)
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Also I am getting this warning:

> TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\Builds\2\Test\Test-CI\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: you probably have create bug on build failed turned on but I do not know why you would get the bug type cannot be found....

Comment: Now i am getting this error Exception Message: There is no working folder mapping for $/Test/Main/Source-Dev/Service/Test/test.sln. (type ItemNotMappedException)

Answer (score 0):

Most the time I see TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\Builds\2\Test\Test-CI\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions. it sets off alarm bells about the solutions/projects. Generally it means someone has checked in the bin or obj folders which then leads to this error when build compiles things and tries to overwrite dlls in the bin folder with new copies but those are marked as read only when they are pulled into the build working directory. If you have bin or obj folders checked into tfs delete them and rebuild.

Comment: Stiil facing the same issue after deleting bin and obj folder form TFS. Can you help me on the error as well?

Comment: Do you have a work item type named 'bug' in the team project? Have you customized work item templates? Chances are there is a non-compatible customization in your process template that was used for the team project.

Comment: Did you check in (non-gated) the deletes?